# Simple Microsoft example of a C++ window does not compile

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I've read the Microsoft page on how to create a simple window in C++. Here is the code:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  // Register the window class.
  const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

  WNDCLASS wc = { };

  wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
  wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

  RegisterClass(&wc);

  // Create the window.

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
  );

  if (hwnd == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

  // Run the message loop.

  MSG msg = {};
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;

    case WM_PAINT: {
      PAINTSTRUCT ps;
      HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

      FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1));


      EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The above code does not compile. It is highly unlikely that Microsoft has posted broken code, so I am quite sure I've gone wrong somewhere. I copied the code into a file (**window.cpp**), and compiled using MinGW:

```
$ g++ window.cpp -o window.exe
```

It returns an error:

> C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function 'main':
>      C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to 'WinMain'
>      collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Why though? I am compiling any other C++ program in the same way. Why doesn't this one compile?

Comment: `wWinMain` should be `WinMain`

Comment: Do you really want to name your executable `-window.exe` ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792275/difference-between-winmain-and-wwinmain

Comment: @drescherjm [`wWinMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) is correct for Unicode programs.

Comment: The error is `undefined reference to 'WinMain'` however.

Comment: i think that you need define `-municode` command switch. must be not `lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o` but `lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_w.o` lib referenced. for example - https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/25651370/

Comment: [*you should use the `-municode` option*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11706847/6401656)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Visual Studio? Windows programming not only needs compiling, but also debugging, profiling, [...]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wWinmain, Unicode, and Mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3571250/608639). Also see the related question [undefined reference to `WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5259714/608639).

Comment: Regarding Michael's comment and the Microsoft compiler, you can get the toolchain *without* Visual Studio. Also see [download microsoft build tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=download+microsoft+build+tools).

Comment: @drescherjm no, that's a typo. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MinGW-64 default settings, the compiler is looking for `main` or `WinMain`. It doesn't recognize `wWinMain` as an entry point.

Add `-municode` option so the compiler will expect `wWinMain`

```
g++ window.cpp -municode -o window.exe
```

(also add `-mwindows` option if you don't want a console window)

---

In MinGW-32, only `main` and `WinMain` are expected entry points by default. Use the following:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
```

Note `LPSTR` parameter in `WinMain`, it has to be `LPSTR` even when `UNICODE` is defined. Use `GetCommandLineW()` if you want the Unicode command line argument.

---

In Visual Studio, simply use `wWinMain` for Unicode.

Comment: i think that this is not visual studio specific - for [example](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/25651370/) - possible **-municode** switch need use. anyway support for [`wWinMain`](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c) exist in mingw too

Comment: @RbMm you are right. I didn't know MinGW-64 has that option.

Comment: how i understand latest builds must have this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571250/wwinmain-unicode-and-mingw/11706847#11706847

Answer (score 0):

The main function needs to be called WinMain.  You have a function called wWinMain.  I assume that is a typo, either by you or in the example code.

Incidentally, the error is from the linker, not the compiler.  It's saying you don't have WinMain defined anywhere.

Edited to add: I was mostly wrong (thanks for the other contributors for setting me right). The linker was *in this case* looking for WinMain rather than wWinMain. I assume to be correct the advice given on how to change this; I'm not familiar enough with the particular toolchain to comment.

Comment: [`wWinMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) is correct for Unicode programs.

Comment: this is not typo - https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c#L10 based on [`WPRFLAG`](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c#L325) called [`wmain`](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c#L16) or [`main`](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c#L14)