# What do I have to do to make wWinMain the main function and not WinMain?

Tags: c++

I have a question, I do not use Visual Studio because my computer has low resources and the packages are very slow when downloading them from my internet, therefore I use Visual Studio Code with MinGW as a c/c++ compiler . But I have a problem with creating programs with window windows, although I was looking in the documentation, I would like someone to tell me: how can I define the wWinMain function as the main function, I literally copied the programs from the documentation (which shows how to do this example) and I get this error: " undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status", I'm still learning so I would appreciate it if you could help me with this

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792275/difference-between-winmain-and-wwinmain)? If your program is not compiled with wide-character support for the Windows API, then the entry point will be `WinMain`.

Comment: Include the relevant code snippet, please.

Comment: Question is possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324230/undefined-reference-to-winmain-c-mingw

Comment: `-municode`, I believe?